# Как взять значение input-а не в строчный тип,а в числовой для калькулятора чтобы прибавить два значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 
 $('button').on('click',function(){
  var a,b,c,d;
  a=$('#val1').val();
  b=$('#val2').val();
  alert(a+b);
 });


 
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #333;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
}
div{
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px;
 border-color: white;
}
input{
 margin:5px;
 padding: 5px;
}
b{
 color:white;
 margin:7px;
 padding: 7px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mypracticetest</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 


</head>
<body>
 
 <div align="center">
  <b>Калькулятор</b><br>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val1"><br/>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val2"><br/>
  <button>Ответ</button>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `a = +$('#val1').val();`

Comment: смотрите,val берёт значение и превращает в строчный тип и  числа прибавить нельзя,хочу узнать что поставить вместо val,чтобы смог прибавить числа.

Comment: я вам ето и написал(`+` - в нем вся магия), и вон вам еще и ответ написали

Comment: спасибо,я новичок в этом деле и не сразу понял. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из инпута вы получаете всегда строку, по этому её нужно ["перевести" в "число"](https://learn.javascript.ru/type-conversions#chislennoe-preobrazovanie)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var a, b, c, d;
  a = Number($('#val1').val());
  b = Number($('#val2').val());
  alert(a + b);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

b {
  color: white;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
  <b>Калькулятор</b><br>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val1"><br/>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val2"><br/>
  <button>Ответ</button>
</div>
```

---

Либо используйте [`eval()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var a, b, c, d;
  a = $('#val1').val();
  b = $('#val2').val();
  alert(eval(a+'+'+b));
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

b {
  color: white;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
  <b>Калькулятор</b><br>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val1"><br/>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val2"><br/>
  <button>Ответ</button>
</div>
```

Comment: если посмотрите в html код то увидите что я сделал так чтобы и input-е могли написать только числа,я вот хочу поменять тип в число в коде javascript.Вместо val() написал eval()  не помогло

Comment: спасибо,я новичок в этом деле и не сразу понял. Спасибо за помощь